# New Behavioral Triggers No Data in Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, commerce-cloud, einstein-recommendations, behavioral-triggers

Has anyone used these yet? Very new, they just released them within the past couple of months. I have collect tracking code installed and I am seeing that carts are tracking in Web and Mobile Analytics. I created a Behavioral Trigger which in turn automatically created an abandoned cart. But I've abandoned several carts and still not data in them. Also, the carts I am showing in Web and Mobile Analytics are from yesterday and I do not have the ability to select today as an option. I hope that they don't seriously make you wait a day. What if I wanted to trigger the email an hour after they left the page?

Has anyone used this new feature? Any ideas?

**EDIT: When I added the trackCart code to my page manually, I got data in the data extension. The issue is that Commerce Cloud is not firing properly. I'm looking into this and will update this when I find out more. One thing that did occur was that the email did not fire. This is because the data extension that was created automatically by the system did not have an email field.**

Comment: What is your session time out set to. And is the item in your cart set to available = Y?

Comment: Are you saying that your PI Data Extensions do not have data in them? You must go into setting and activate Data Extensions.

Comment: @EazyE it's set to 15 minutes and yes, OnlineAvailability is set to Y

Comment: @EazyE what I'm still unclear on is if there are any modifications that need to be made to the trackCart call or if it should work as is

Comment: if you go to reporting >> contacts and search for the value passed in setuserinfo, do they show a cart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was the Commerce Cloud was missing a hook in one of the added TurnTo cartridges. I don't have the full details, but apparently, the way the cartridges work is that they overwrite previous cartridges in the stack. TurnTo was overwriting the Marketing Cloud cartridge and had omitted a hook call that was needed. So it was a matter of copy/pasting that hook from the Marketing Cloud cartridge. But don't ask me to point out which file that was in, since I didn't find it...

Answer (score 2):

First things to check:

- Make sure you have a product catalog configured in your business unit.
- Make sure that the "item" variables in the trackCart command match the product code in your catalog.
- In Behavioral Triggers, click on 'Status' to get more information about your Collect Tracking Code installation.

Comment: Thanks @Rick for your comment. I realize now that it's because something is not configured in Commerce Cloud